# ArcGIS 10.2.1 working with time and reporting when feature geometry has changed

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-10.2, time, timeslider

I'm working, with ArcGIS 10.2, ona whole lot of petroleum licencing data that chops and changes, in active areas, on a relatively frequent period. i collect the geometry data month by month (saving the copy as a feature class) and then copy the new geometry outs as new features to a feature class that represents the accumulation of geometries over time.

The product, described below, is designed to answer: **When has this licence's geometry changed?** *This is important as companies change their licences for a reason either through business deals, partnerships or failed ventures etc...*

I have created a product that will show 90-captures of a geometry due to the time period data has been gathered for. However, due to the nature of the licencing data a lot of licence areas remain unchanged for long periods of time thus making working with the data a bit cumbersome.

For now it is manageable for me to use definition queries to sample a single licence and with the time slider play the history stopping when the geometry changes, making a note of this for later for further analysis (i.e. presenting the time stamps for change as well as a map of the geometry change)

So, after setting the scene the question is: **Is there a way, using Python, to print the date (an attribute field) of a licence for when its geometry changes?**

or

**Is it possible to select a feature in a time-enabled layer and detect when its geometry changes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have feature classes representing your licencing data each month, and I am assuming that a licence retains its unique idea even when its geometry changes, you should be able to use the [Feature Compare (Data Management)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000004000000) tool to detect which licences had their geometry change from one month to the next:

> Compares two feature classes or layers and returns the comparison
>   results. Feature Compare can report differences with **geometry**, tabular
>   values, spatial reference, and field definitions.

This tool would form the basis of your Python script that could do pairwise comparisons of your feature classes chronologically and write a table of licence IDs and geometry change dates.